# Why am I getting this error in Joomla?

Tags: mysql, joomla3.0

I am getting the following message in Joomla:

[image: Description of issue]

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

These is unrelated to joomla, is related to a third part developer extension JooDB ask them in their developer forum

Comment: Thanks for your answer.